# Sporadic ad-hoc topic challenge

Tags: discussion, challenge

There’s only 2 questions tagged [2d](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d), yet that’s a very interesting subject.

So I challenge the community to post on this topic, and discover existing posts that can have this tag added.

> For questions with an element that only has two dimensions: length and width. This tag is only relevant when describing something that is often not two-dimensional.

> Questions with this tag focus on objects, spaces and other elements that possess length and width but not height. The spacetime-dimensions tag is often relevant.
>
> If your fictional universe is two-dimensional, it is difficult to use the science-based tag. See the Physics SE discussion on the subject, which explains the problems asssociated with such a world.

Comment: Could you add a tag wiki?

Comment: So to be picky. But "sporadic" and "ad-hoc"? Both words seem superfluous to your challenge. A title of "Topic challenge" should be enough, and on topic too. You could add, say, 'Two-dimensional" for subject specificity.

Comment: “Sporadic” because it’s not the fortnightly topic challenge, ans “ad-hoc” because it's not any official organized effort by the whole community.

Comment: Is the wiki weakened by announcing the two-dimensional universe limitation?  Are we trying to limit the use of the tag only to 2D issues in a 3D universe?

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be a great challenge, so I'm looking for ways to "bump" the question.  Upvoting it didn't work.  Editing it doesn't seem to have worked.  Therefore, I'm announcing that I happily posted a [2d](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d) question to bravely meet the challenge.  I'm hoping the answer might "bump" the question as I, too, would like to see more interest in the concept.

Comment: I presume by "bump" you mean "upgrading" or "enhancing" the question. "Bump" has meant to knock something off or over or even jostle it (which be done in fun or with malice -- to add to the confusion). I look forward to finding your [tag:2d] question. Hope you do more like this. Yay! Plus one.